# What should I do about working in a laboratory that I believe is unsafe?

Tags: safety

I currently work in a lab that frequently gives me anxiety about safety. We work with toxic fumes daily. The sliding sashes on the fume hoods are held up by cinder blocks. There is a large crack in the glass of one of the hoods. We have an abundance of work so everyone is always rushing through SOPs. I see people pull beakers out while toxic gases are still fuming. We've never even had a safety drill on what to do if there is a chemical spill. We had an audit a few months ago and somehow passed? How should I address this situation? Thank you.

Comment: I don't know that this deserves a downvote, but it is a very broad question.  Issues of such importance are probably best addressed through your institution, but the means by which to do so vary from country to country.  It sounds like your lab passed "inspection", but perhaps the examiners didn't look closely enough, or things were covered up.  Failing correction at the level of the institution, you have a right to go to OSHA (in the States) or the equivalent governing body.

Comment: Please don't deface your question.  You can flag it for deletion if you so choose.

Comment: You should be cautious and follow written down procedures because whistle-blowers are often treated badly.